# can't click on the link in the email

Tags: php, symfony

I am using fosUserBundle in my symfony project. And i'm trying to confirm the user's registration by mail. The user is able to receive the email containing the email to click on it in order activate his account but the problem is that he can't click on it so in order to active his account he has to copy paste the link in the browser.
Can you please help me solve this issue and make it easier on the user so he will be able to click on the link and be directed directly?
here's the code i'm using:

## app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
# ...

service:
mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
resetting: 
    email:
        template: email/password_resetting.email.twig
```

## app/Resources/views/email/password_resetting.email.twig

```
{# app/Resources/views/email/password_resetting.email.twig #}

{% block subject %}Resetting your password{% endblock %}

{% block body_text %}
{% autoescape false %}
Hello {{ user.username }} !

You can reset your password by accessing {{ confirmationUrl }}

Greetings,
the App team
{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body_html %}

{% include 'email/password_resetting.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: We can help you only when you show some code, with statements only we can't help.

Comment: Please let us know the version of FOSUserBundle you're using

Answer (score 0):

From your issue description, I understand email is sent as plain text, therefore customer's email client does not parse the link as an HTML link.

> The default mailer only supports sending plain text messages. If you
>   want to send multipart messages, the easiest solution is to use the
>   TwigSwiftMailer implementation instead.

Please check [FOSUserBundle documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#sending-html-mails) for sending emails in HTML format.

Comment: i tried what you told me George but i'm receiving the error 
Unable to find template "email/password_resetting.html.twig" in email\password_resetting.email.twig at line 22. Isn't it an html that i'm inherinting from fosuserbundle?

Comment: I added my code to my question and thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default FOSUserBundle email template.

In **app/config/config.yml** comment out or delete the 'template' option:

```
resetting: 
    email:
        # template: email/password_resetting.email.twig
```

Next, recursively create directories:

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Resetting/
```

This is the exact directory structure as in FOSUser vendor directory.

Copy email.txt.twig from vendor/ and place it in:

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Resetting/email.txt.twig
```

Now, make all the necessary adjustements in your template.

Remember, the bundle uses translations by default so you might want to change or delete the line in the template:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
```